# Is there any performance difference between Gigabyte AORUS m.2 NVMe SSDs with & without heat-sink

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, nvme, m.2

I have one doubt regarding AORUS NVMe SSDs. I would like to purchase 1 TB Gen 4 m.2 NVMe, and I came though AORUS. I was able to see two SSDs, one with a copper heat sink and other without. I would like to know if there is any performance difference between them, because the one with copper heat sink has higher price than the other. I have Asus Zenith II Extreme Alpha motherboard which comes with m.2 heat-sink module, and so I think I don't need another Heat Sink.Below are the links of SSDs.

With HS https://www.gigabyte.com/in/Solid-State-Drive/AORUS-NVMe-Gen4-SSD-1TB#kf

Without HS https://www.gigabyte.com/in/Solid-State-Drive/AORUS-Gen4-SSD-1TB#kf

Thanks.